# Hibernate Config in Properties outside of the WAR without Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have this structure in my Jboss 6.4, and I need to access outside of the war to another folder to take the configuration for Hibernate:

/usr/webapps/MYAPP/deployments/MYAPP.war

/usr/webapps/MYAPP/appconfig/hibernate.properties

I have to use this pattern, and I'm using Hibernate 4.2, in my case I need to take the content of the properties file to use it in my **hibernate.cfg.xml** like here:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">${db.driver}</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">${db.url}</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">${db.username}</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">${db.password}</property>
```

hibernate.properties:

```
db.username=usernameTest
db.password=passwordTest
db.driver=driverTest
db.url=urlTest
db.dialect=dialectTest
```

What should be the best practice to do this, I was watching some cases with Spring here, but in my case it's only with JEE

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your use case clearly. If you would like your XML file to be loaded by other applications outside of your WAR, you can deploy the XML file as a JBoss Module and then add a reference to the module in the other applications via `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` or in the `META-INF` file. By the way, I would recommend using `persistence.xml` and following JPA 2.0 (hibernate 4 implements JPA 2.0) to make life easier later by following JEE6 standards.